# About current distributions and skin effect

Tags: skin-effect

I'm reading a book about signal integrity.
And I have a question.

[image]

[image]

Within each conductor, the current wants to spread apart to decrease its partial self-inductance.
-> I don't understand the reason why for the current to spread apart will decrease it's self-inductance.

Could anybody explain me the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't that image be in actual text?

Comment: Look up reluctance and eddy currents.

Answer (score 1):

The flux around each wire with AC current will cancel in between the wires when almost touching. This coupling reduces the  loop area as well which reduces the overall inductance. It also raises the capacitance between the wires and lowers the characteristic impedance. e.g. twisted pairs.

Skin effect reduces the cross-sectional area and raises the resistance as well as be forced to conduct in the outer surface depending on the frequency. This is because the eddy currents cancel in the centre raising the resistance forcing the current flow on the outer skin.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I think I have to study eddy current. Thank you.